# How can I declare the json id's globally and pass it into the API request by using a global variable?

Tags: java, android, json

Please say me how can i declare all the brand's id globally on to a single global variable and pass it as a parameter in http request?

As specified, I need to declare the brand id of all the five below mentioned brands as a integer  in a single global variable and pass it on to the request as a parameters in the form of integers

I have provided my API response below:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,----> brand id
      "name": "AUDI",
      "code": "AUDI",
      "image": "",
      "status": "1",
      "created_at": "2016-09-27 00:07:38",
      "updated_at": "2016-09-27 00:07:38"
    },
    {
      "id": 2-----> brand id
      "name": "Bravian Motor Works",
      "code": "BMW",
      "image": "",
      "status": "1",
      "created_at": "2016-09-27 00:07:58",
      "updated_at": "2016-09-27 00:07:58"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,---->brand id
      "name": "AB Volvo",
      "code": "VOLVO",
      "image": "",
      "status": "1",
      "created_at": "2016-09-27 00:08:36",
      "updated_at": "2016-09-27 00:08:36"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,-----> brand id
      "name": "Ford Motor Company",
      "code": "FORD",
      "image": "",
      "status": "1",
      "created_at": "2016-09-27 00:11:51",
      "updated_at": "2016-09-27 00:11:51"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,-----> brand id
      "name": "Maruti Suzuki",
      "code": "Maruti",
      "image": "",
      "status": "1",
      "created_at": "2016-09-27 00:12:14",
      "updated_at": "2016-09-27 00:12:14"
    }
  ],
  "msg": "success",
  "info": "data list"
}
```

And i need to pass the global variable as shown below:

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://garage.kaptastech.mobi/api/5k/master/vehicle");

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(7);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id","5"));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registration_no", Regno));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("brand","?"));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("model", "5"));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "1"));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("variant", "1"));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year", Year));
```

I need to pass it in the place of "?"

Comment: Try to save it in arraylist and while passing as a parameter use for loop

Comment: I had tried it  as an arraylist. But on passing it shows an error that array declaration is not allowed here

Comment: Do you want to get response according to particular brand id ? Or you want to get all brands response at once ?

Comment: @piyukataria     I  want to get the response according to the user's selection of the particular brand id. My only requirement is that i need to declare all the brand id under one global variable and pass it as  a parameter in the place of "?" which i had specified in my program

Comment: Yes I am getting your point. save brands data in arraylist using getter-setter and show in listview. After that onItemClickListener of listview, get particular position's brand-id in a variable and pass it in Async task while calling it like:- new yourAcyncTask(brand_id).execute();

Comment: And create a constructor in your Acync task with int(brand_id) as a argument

Comment: @piyukataria can you please show me an example of one brand id so that i  can able to do the other brand id by myself? Or if possible comment me some example links, So that i can look it up easily,since i am new to android development, Thats why I am asking you.

Comment: check my answer that i posted

Comment: @piyukataria So now i  got the point, Actually i am adding the details in my main activity which does not consists of listview, So will it shows any errors if i follow your method?

Comment: Yes if there is no listview then it shows error, You can change it accordingly. But can I know where you are displaying the details So I can explain you in more better way.

Comment: And If you find my answer helpful please upvote

Comment: @piyukataria, definitely. If possible can you say me your email address? So that i will explain you about my project and show  you the screenshot of my current output and the required output? Please share me your email id if you wish to help me, Can you?

Comment: @piyukataria thank you, I will reach you shortly.

Comment: @piyukataria i have mailed you about my project details. Please check your inbox once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your API response in ArrayList and show in ListView and then on onItemClickListener get selected brand id in a variable:-

```
String selectedBrand;

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
        selectedBrand=yourArrayList.get(position).getBrandId();
        new yourAsyncTask(selectedBrand).execute();
    }
});
```

In your Async Task:-

```
class yourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String brand_id;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    public yourAsyncTask(String brand_id)//change argument type accordingly
    {
       this.brand_id=brand_id;
    }
      //use brand_id as a parameter value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the api response in an object. Create a class with those fields and getter + setter.

**Example:**

When you're parsing the api response:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>()
MyObject object = new MyObject();
object.setID(jsonObject.getString("id"));
object.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
// fill other fields
listOfObjects.add(object);
```

Then save the `listOfObjects` where you want. For example a manager.

Then you can call the getters of the object where you need the informations.
For example:

```
// loop over all objects
for(MyObject object : Manager.getInstance().getObjects()) {
  // do whatever you want with these informations
  object.getID();
}
```

Comment: ,can you please show me an example of one brand id so that i can able to do the other brand id by myself? Or if possible comment me some example links, So that i can look it up easily,since i am new to android development, Thats why I am asking you.

Answer (score 0):

Create separate key class where you can store key name globally,
Eg:
create class file as

```
   public class Keys{public static final String KEY_NAME = "keyName";}
```

Use above with class name as:

```
Key.KEY_NAME
```